# Как через цикл нарисовать несколько линий графика в Qt Creator с использованием QCustomPlot

Tags: c++, qtcreator, qt4, qcustomplot

К примеру в `Visual Studio` есть `tChart` и его свойство `Series` ,которое отвечает за рисование линий графика.Вот например такой отрывок кода

```
for (int j = 1; j < Nt - 1; j++)
  {
   for (int i = 1; i < Nt - 1; i++)//Было Nx
    {
        chart2->Series["" + (j + 1).ToString()]->Points->AddXY(i, wht[j][i]);
    }
  }
```

рисует такой график

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `tutorial QCustomPlot` показывается отрисовка графика таким образом.

```
ui->widget_2->graph(0)->setData(x,y);
ui->widget_2->graph(1)->setData(x11,y11);
ui->widget_2->graph(2)->setData(x22,y22);
```

Но что делать когда количество линий графика неизвестно заранее?
Попытка прокрутить через цикл

```
for (int j = 1; j < Nt - 1; j++)
{
ui->widget_2->graph(j+1)->setData(x,y);
}
```

заканчивается вылетом программы и исключением типа:

```
QCPGraph* QCustomPlot::graph(int) const index out of bounds: 2
```

Если же поставить код в цикл получения точек то исключений нету ровно как и графиков.

Если же сделать таким образом:

```
void MainWindow::drawdifnet(int Nt)
{
   //Получаем количество точек для вектора
    int N=Nt;
    int N1=pow(N,2);
    QVector<double> x22(N), y22(N1); // //Массивы координат точек count(j)=10,count(i)=100,i=11,j=11
    int ii=0,jj=0;
    for (int j = 0; j < Nt ; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Nt ; i++)//Было Nx
                {
                    x22[jj]=i;
                    y22[ii]=wht[j][i];
                    ui->widget_2->clearGraphs();
                    ui->widget_2->addGraph();
                    ui->widget_2->graph(0)->setData(x22,y22);
                    ui->widget_2->xAxis->setLabel("OsX");
                    ui->widget_2->yAxis->setLabel("OsY");
                    ui->widget_2->xAxis->setRange(Nt,Nt);
                    ui->widget_2->replot();
                    ii++;
                }
                jj++;
            }
}
```

То выходит непонятное движение одной и той же линии,которая далека от правильного варианта.

**

### UPD-11-08

**

Почему у меня не совпадают размерности векторов?
Дело в том,что у программы принцип работы такой на каждом шаге–итерации j 12 раз вычисляются координаты будущего графика(отсюда и происходит заполнение массива 144 раза) 12 раз по 12.
то есть 12 графиков содержат 12 точек координат

Показываю на рисунках:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждые 12 элементов вектора из 144 точек заполняется постепенно новыми значениями,которые я получаю в ходе итерации цикла.

То есть каждые 12 элементов это координаты каждого следующего графика.

Comment: ui->widget_2->clearGraphs();
ui->widget_2->addGraph();
Вы каждый раз очищаете весь плот и создаете новый график, зачем?
ui->widget_2->graph(0)->setData(x22,y22);
Вектора x22 и y22 должны быть одинакового размера, иначе количество добавленных точек будет равно размеру меньшего из векторов.

Comment: @awesome всё дело в том что эти 144 точки это 12 разных график(их координаты),поэтому вектора не одинаковые.

Смысл такой что за каждый шаг(j) выполняется 12 вычислений и следовательно происходит построение графика по полученным координатам

Comment: Не нужно каждый раз в цикле вызывать clearGraphs().
ui->widget_2->graph(i)->setData(x22,y22); 
Подумайте зачем вам вектор на 100 элементов, если все равно используются только первые 12.

Comment: @awesome не совсем так,у меня используются все 144 точки.
Я сделал правку вопроса и прикрепил рисунки.

Просто сам принцип работы программы будет такой что мы не будем знать заранее сколько элементов будет использовано,может 12 или 13 или 14,а то и больше.

Тот же двумерный массив 'wht[j][i]' динамический

Answer (score 1):

Если вам надо просто нарисовать 12 графиков, состоящих из 12 точек

```
void drawTwelveGraphics(size_t graphsCount)
{
    QVector<double> x(graphsCount);
    QVector<double> y(graphsCount);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < graphsCount; ++i)
    {
        fillVectors(x, y, graphsCount);
        ui->widget_2->addGraph();
        ui->widget_2->graph(i)->setData(x, y);
        ui->widget_2->xAxis->setLabel("OsX");
        ui->widget_2->yAxis->setLabel("OsY");
        ui->widget_2->xAxis->setRange(graphsCount, graphsCount);
        ui->widget_2->replot();
    }
}

void fillVectors(QVector<double>& x, QVector<double>& y, size_t size)
{
  x.clear();
  y.clear();

  for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
    x.push_back((double)(rand() % size));
    y.push_back((double)(rand() % size));
  }
}
```